# CSV to XML hreflang sitemap

Tags: xml, bash, csv

I'm new to bash and scripting so would appreciate some help.

I'm trying to produce an XML file from a csv input to ultimately form a [18n XML sitemap](https://martinkura.com/hreflang-xml-sitemap-3-examples-can-steal/).

My CSV is structured as follows

iso language
**column header**

en,de,fr

**rows**

en-url,de-ulr,fr-url

en-url2,de-url2,fr-url2

I'd like to csv to output into an XML sitemap format:

```
 <url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>             #first column (second line)
<xhtml:link 
           rel="alternate"
           hreflang="de"                                        #second column iso value (first line)
           href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>    #second column URL (second line)
<xhtml:link 
           rel="alternate"
           hreflang="fr"                                       #third column iso value (first line)   
           href="http://www.example.com/french/page.html"/>    #third column URL (second line)  
 </url>
```

This will then iterate through all values in the first column to produce a full sitemap.

The script I've cobbled together isn't providing me with the expected output and I've become a bit stuck as I'm struggling to control/echo values from within the array.

My script currently outputs the following

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>en</loc> 
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="fr"
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="fr"
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="fr"
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>example.com</loc> 
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="example.com" href="example.fr"
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="example.com" href="example.fr"
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="example.com" href="example.fr"
  </url>
```

My script

```html
`#!/bin/bash
file_in="sample.csv"
file_out="sample.xml"

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' > $file_out
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
echo '  <url>' >> $file_out
echo '    <loc>'${arry[0]}'</loc> '>> $file_out
for u in "${arry[@]}"
do
echo '<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="'${arry[0]}'" href="'${arry[2]}'"'>> $file_out
done
echo '  </url>' >> $file_out
done < $file_in
echo '</urlset>' >> $file_out`
```

In a nutshell, the script is echoing elements from within index of the array, not the column. In addition, the hreflang value needs to be escaped from the loop so it stays as a constant in the hreflang="" value in the output.

If anybody has some tips on how I can store columns as individual arrays or how I iterate overvalues in a csv column, this would be HUGELY helpful.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlstarlet/info).

Comment: Your desired output is no valid XML. You use namespace `xhtml` without definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an XML file, then I would definitely use the right tools for the job.

Because Bash doesn't understand XML, I would recommend a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) that does.

I'm going to assume '*input.csv*':

```
en,de,fr
http://www.example.com/english/page.html,http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html,http://www.example.com/french/page.html
```

**1. Convert the csv-file to a series of "transposed" sequences**

```
$ xidel -s input.csv -e 'x:lines($raw) ! array{tokenize(.,",")}'
["en", "de", "fr"]
["http://www.example.com/english/page.html", "http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html", "http://www.example.com/french/page.html"]

$ xidel -s input.csv -e '
  let $ln:=x:lines($raw) ! array{tokenize(.,",")} return
  (1 to count($ln[1]())) ! join($ln(.))
'
en http://www.example.com/english/page.html
de http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html
fr http://www.example.com/french/page.html

$ xidel -s input.csv -e '
  let $ln:=x:lines($raw) ! array{tokenize(.,",")} return
  (2 to count($ln[1]())) ! join($ln(.))
'
de http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html
fr http://www.example.com/french/page.html
```

**2. Convert these sequences to XML**

```
xidel -s input.csv -e '
  let $ln:=x:lines($raw) ! array{tokenize(.,",")} return
  <urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
      <loc>{$ln[2](1)}</loc>
      {(2 to count($ln[1]())) ! <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="{$ln(.)[1]}" href="{$ln(.)[2]}"/>}
    </url>
  </urlset>
' --output-format=xml --output-node-indent --output-declaration='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.example.com/french/page.html"/>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

(if your shell is already set to UTF-8, then `--output-declaration` is optional)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a minor change to your script. It will capture the the column headers in an array to make processing easier.

Code assume input.csv is

```
en,de,fr
en-url,de-ulr,fr-url
en-url2,de-url2,fr-url2
```

Script (see note below about redirection).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Redirect input and output
file_in="sample.csv"
file_out="sample.xml"
exec < $file_in >$file_out

# XML Header
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'

# Read column headers into langs
IFS=$, read -r -a langs
# number of alternate languages
n_langs=${#langs[@]}

# Loop over data
# Read line of URLs
while IFS=$',' read -r -a urls
do
    echo "  <url>"
    echo "    <loc>${urls[0]}</loc> "
    # Loop of alternative languages
    for ((lx=1 ; lx<n_langs ; lx++)) ; do
        echo "    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang='${langs[lx]}' href='${urls[lx]}' />"
    done
    echo "  </url>"
done
echo "</urlset>"
```

Notes:

- Script uses single quote for XML attribute. This simplies quoting on bash script.
- It is common to parameterize the script input/output. Instead of hardcoding the input and output, consider removing the first 3 lines (file_in=... thru exec), and invoke the script with redirection: `script.sh < sample.csv > sample.xml`